# Find atributes in a csv file python

Tags: python, csv

i have a file `atributes.csv` like this:

```
Ethnics   HairColor   EyeColor  HairStyle

European     Red       Blue      Short
European     Blonde    Dark      Short
European     Brown     Green     Long
Asian        Brown     Dark      Medium
```

and another `db.csv` like this:

```
Name   Id  Ethnics  HairColor  HairStyle  EyeColor

Ana    11  European   Red      Short      Blue
Ion     8  European   Brown    Short      Dark
Ryan   24  Asian      Brown    Short      Blue
Mike   13  European   Brown    Short      Blue
Paul    9  European   Blonde   Short      Dark
Sam     1  European   Brown    Short      Green
John    4  European   Blonde   Long       Green
Chung   6  Asian      Brown    Medium     Dark
```

i would like to write into antoher csv file `final.csv` lines which contains atributes from `atributes.csv` for example

```
Ana    11  European   Red      Short      Blue
Paul    9  European   Blonde   Short      Dark
Chung   6  Asian      Brown    Medium     Dark
```

i write this code but didnt`t work

```
import csv
import os

f = open('atributes.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader)
f1 = open('db.csv', 'r')
reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
next(reader1)

ofile = open('final.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(ofile)
for line1 in reader :
        for line2 in reader1 :
                        if line1[0]== line2[2] and line1[1]== line2[3] and line1[2]== line2[5] and line1[3]== line2[4]:
                                writer.writerow(line2)

f.close()
f1.close()
ofile.close()
```

Comment: What's the logic you are trying to apply? You are trying to find matches? You should have a look at pandas library for this.

Comment: i think i am trying to parse first file 1st  line and then to parse all the 2nd file to search for solutions and then go to the next line of 1st file and then search solutions in second file, hope u understand :)

Comment: You indicate that the delimiter is a comma `,` but the formatting of your data files uses whitespace to delimit fields. Which one is correct?

Comment: @sam data in file are sth like this "Ana,11,European,Red,Short,Blue"

Comment: yea i have a probltem there in for... and i cant find

Comment: @PaulNovac i dont see anything in attributes.csv that you need, you have all the data in db.csv, are you excluding fields? How do you link them? just on Ethnics  HairColor  HairStyle  EyeColor ? This sounds like an amazing fit for sqlite specially if you have 100k+ correction. i see, attributes are your fitler. ok i get it

Comment: Last question, how many items would you have in attributes at any one time?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi, i have to sort db.csv by atributes.csv and if there are persons who didnt match with these atributes i wont write them in final.csv

Comment: @JavierBuzzi i have about 325 combinations of atributes in atributes.csv

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The python solution: (this can be improved upon but i can't see this beating sqlite to be honest)

```
import csv
import os

matches = set()
with open('attributes.tsv', 'r') as f:
    attrs = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for attr in attrs:
        matches.add('{Ethnics}/{HairColor}/{HairStyle}/{EyeColor}'.format(**attr))

with open('db.tsv', 'r') as f1, open('final.csv', 'w') as ofile:
    db = csv.DictReader(f1, delimiter='\t')
    clean = csv.DictWriter(ofile, ('Name', 'Id', 'Ethnics', 'HairColor', 'HairStyle', 'EyeColor',), delimiter='\t')

    for item in db:
        key = '{Ethnics}/{HairColor}/{HairStyle}/{EyeColor}'.format(**item)
        if key in matches:
            clean.writerow(item)
```

Couple of things:

1. You cannot have a blank line between your headers and your data
2. You need to name "attribute" correctly
3. You need to rename your files .tsv

Very preliminary tests show:

```
$ time python code.py 

real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.016s

$ time sqlite ... the code bellow

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```

`0m0.012s` vs `0m0.038s` i think sqlite is the clear winner...

---

*Old answer:*

First thing; I realize you want to do this with python, BUT i guarantee this is WAYYY faster, specially since you're telling me there could be more than 325 attributes.. something tells me that can grow, this is a very robust solution.

I did make some assumptions: you're on a *nix machine.. If you're not, i'll give you the python code -- but it wont be as fast, i guarantee it

```
# clean up space mess.. you will probably not need this (but you do need to remove the line between your header and your data)
cat attributes.csv | perl -p -e 's/[ ]+/\t/g' | sed '2d' > attributes.tsv
# import the data into the filter
printf '.mode tabs\n.import attributes.tsv attributes\n' | sqlite3 filter.db
# clean up space mess.. you will probably not need this (but you do need to remove the line between your header and your data)
cat db.csv | perl -p -e 's/[ ]+/\t/g' | sed '2d' > db.tsv
# import the data into the filter
printf '.mode tabs\n.import db.tsv db\n' | sqlite3 filter.db
# output the results
sqlite3 -separator $'\t' -header filter.db 'select db.* from db '`
`'inner join attributes attr on attr.Ethnics = db.Ethnics '`
`'and attr.HairColor = db.HairColor and attr.HairStyle = db.HairStyle '`
`'and attr.EyeColor = db.EyeColor'
# cleanup
rm db.tsv attributes.tsv filter.db
```

Sample out:

```
Name    Id  Ethnics     HairColor   HairStyle   EyeColor
Ana     11  European    Red         Short       Blue
Paul    9   European    Blonde      Short       Dark
Chung   6   Asian       Brown       Medium      Dark
```

Comment: 'The Hell! I beg to differ. The Python code to make this work is simple and doesn't require an SQLite database!!! Downvoted as this is not what the OP requested

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I'll write it in python. I'll do some benchmarks, hypothesis: sqlite performance is king

Comment: than you, man but i dont know to code in pearl, sorry i will apreciate if you can write code in python :d

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack very simple test, using his simple 6 lines of test data. Looks like sqlite is faster.. 3x faster almost. Funny thing is, the data sqlite is using is not even indexed... probably be 4-5x faster when indexed and if this is meant to be using thousands of records, python will fall flat on its face, sqlite will remain in the sub second -- guaranteed.

Comment: I’m not disputing the runtime performance of your answer but it’s simply not what the OP asked for. If the OP had asked for a faster version in Shell, then perhaps your answer would be on topic.

Comment: can you explain me why you used format(**attr) and what it does? ty

Comment: @PaulNovac it’s a feature of string format, you can do something like: `’{name}’.format(name=‘john’)` this is the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pandas approach:

```
data1 = '''\
Ethnics   HairColor   EyeColor  HairStyle
European     Red       Blue      Short
European     Blonde    Dark      Short
European     Brown     Green     Long
Asian        Brown     Dark      Medium'''

data2 = '''\
Name   Id  Ethnics  HairColor  HairStyle  EyeColor

Ana    11  European   Red      Short      Blue
Ion     8  European   Brown    Short      Dark
Ryan   24  Asian      Brown    Short      Blue
Mike   13  European   Brown    Short      Blue
Paul    9  European   Blonde   Short      Dark
Sam     1  European   Brown    Short      Green
John    4  European   Blonde   Long       Green
Chung   6  Asian      Brown    Medium     Dark'''

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data1), sep='\s+') 
df2 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data2), sep='\s+')

#df1 = pd.read_csv('atributes.csv') # Uncomment this row
#df2 = pd.read_csv('db.csv') # Uncomment this row

cols = df1.columns.tolist()
s = set(df1.set_index(cols).index)
df_out = df2[df2.set_index(cols).index.isin(s)]

df_out.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

Final.csv:

```
Name,Id,Ethnics,HairColor,HairStyle,EyeColor
Ana,11,European,Red,Short,Blue
Paul,9,European,Blonde,Short,Dark
Chung,6,Asian,Brown,Medium,Dark
```

Comment: Pandas?! Loading both entire sets?! What if the db.csv is a couple of petabytes.. This does not scale at all

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Well if you only going to run it once you might as well keep it simple. *.csv I associate with quite small files and that should work.

Comment: i`v got some errors from this panda :)) can you help me? sorry i`m a little bit noob :d                                                                                                           df_out = df2.loc[pd.Series(df2.set_index(cols).index.values).map(m).fillna(False)                        \pandas\core\frame.py", line 3146, in set_index
    level = frame[col]._values

Comment: @AntonvBR, i added the data as string and program crushed :d... i think its too much data

Comment: @AntonvBR, i will add photos in post ok? cuz there i cant post photos

Comment: @AntonvBR, i changed in file with notepad "," with "  " using replace all

Comment: @AntonvBR,can you give me ur mail adress?